# How do I style the SSRS ReportServer?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I have set up Reporting Services and added some reports. When i view them in ReportManager I get a nice folder like structure with icons etc.

When I view them in /ReportServer/, there is no structure, it is like viewing a folder in html as you can see below:

[image: SSRS]

My question is, how do I make ReportServer look like ReportManager? or at least anything more user friendly?

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 1):

The /ReportServer is the SSRS web service. When you access it with a browser, you get the minimalistic directory listing view, but it isn't meant to be used that way. There is no way to easily style it or make it look like the ReportManager. You'd have to manually hack the CSS files in the SSRS installation folder.

The SSRS web service is intended to be used "behind the scenes" by other applications that need access to SSRS functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the "Web Service URL", which basically contains all the folder structure with all its content. What you need to access is the "Report Manager URL", which is slightly different but through a different service, is providing access to the same content.

If you go to the Reporting Services Configuration Manager tool, and connect to the server/instance you're working in, you'll see both url's.

You don't have any reason to use the web service instead of the Report Manager, so there's no point in trying to make the web service look like Report Manager.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I see, however, when I am testing them out it seems that the ReportServer loads much faster than the ReportManager and therefore assumed this was the one I am supposed to be using to provide access to reports to users. How do other people provide access to their reports?

Comment: Not really. First, possibly you need to identify WHEN does it take longer to load, it's noteworthy that SSRS service takes long time to respond after it has gone to "sleep" (sometime minutes). So what sometimes happens is that Report Manager takes very long to load because it's the first time it processes a request after a long period of inactivity.

Comment: Regarding how users are given access to reports, it depends on how do you want to distribute the data and if it's time sensitive. Subscriptions is one controlled way to deliver specific data controlling when and how is getting it. Otherwise I've always used Report Manager and never had a reason to use the other service.